# How to draw a circular heatmap within a rectangle in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

Say I have an image and I have a bounding box on a part of the image. How can I draw a circular heatmap within this rectangle?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean? Your question is very unclear. And why did you tag this with [user-experience]?

Comment: For example, I have an image and I bound the hat in the image with a bounding box. Now I would like to draw a circular heatmap in this bounding box. i.e., the center of the my heatmap should be the center of the bounding box, and the color of my heatmap fades away as the radius increases until the edge of my heatmap reaches the bounding box.

Comment: So you want to draw a radial color gradient in a circle? Does "heatmap" really mean something related to data, or do you just want to somehow move from color A to color B? You see, your question is also very broad.

Comment: Yes, I just need a way to draw a gradient circle within a rectangle given the x and y positions of the rectangle. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Axes` in the desired position, and use a polar `pcolor` plot to construct a "heatmap":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
# plot dummy image
ax1.imshow(np.random.rand(200,200),cmap='viridis')

# create new Axes, position is in figure relative coordinates!
relpos = [0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
ax2 = fig.add_axes(relpos, polar=True)
ax2.axis('off')
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
r = np.linspace(0,1,50)
gradient = np.tile(np.linspace(0,1,r.size)[:,None],phi.size)
ax2.pcolor(gradient,cmap='hot_r')
```

The result:

[image: result]

The color gradient samples linearly from the colormap, in the above example named `hot_r`. You can play around with both the colormap and with the transition of the `gradient` variable, the result will always be radially dependent.

The only thing you need to take care of is to transform your rectangle (given in units which only you can tell) to relative figure units (where (0,0) is the bottom left corner of the figure, and (1,1) is the top left). The axis positioning works in the way which is usual for box-shaped objects: `[left,bottom,width,height]`.